# alert() prompt - Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, alert

With alerts you can have text inputs. I was hoping you could put check boxes in. Is this possible?

http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_popup.asp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you would need to build out a dialog box in order to achieve this.

You are able to achieve this with relative ease through [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and more specifically the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) plugin, allowing [dialog boxes](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) to come up without too much know-how

Comment: jQuery UI has a brilliant one. It's just a shame the UI framework is so huge. Oh well, needs must.

Comment: It is indeed huge. Once you become more advanced with JavaScript or jquery, you'll be able to produce your own stuff like dialogs with 1/5 of the code - frameworks certainly do help make life easier, though :)

Answer (score 7):

No. The only options are:

- alert (display string);
- confirm (display string and get yes/no|true/false back);
- prompt (display string and get input string back)

You can create your own [modal dialog](http://javascript.about.com/library/blmodald3.htm) using a variety of techniques. Under the hood, they all essentially do the same thing - display a separate web page in a popup window or iFrame and disable input access to the rest of the browser until the popup is closed. These are pretty easy to get wrong (hard to use + very annoying) but when done right they offer the developer a lot of power - since it's a complete web page you control, you can pass complex JavaScript objects between the dialog and the main browser window, instead of having to rely on the primitive interaction modes offered by the out-of-the-box dialogs.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty shure it isn't possible. However, you can simulate a "alert box" with the contents you need. JQuery, for example, is a great javascript framework to achieve that.

Comment: All the answers got downed, no one ever bothered commenting why.

Answer (score 3):

no, but you can create a function that opens a alert box with html in it, like on facebook.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can create functions with alert boxes.

```
javascript:alert("Hello");
javascript:confirm("Hello");
javascript:prompt("Hello");
```

are the inly available ones.