# How to echo Check Box in JavaScript Alert When Click on Submit Button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am new in JavaScript. I have a form code in which i have some `input type` and a `submit` button. I want that when user click on `Submit` button then an alert is open having 3 check boxes and two button `Ok` and `Cancel` When user check all checkbox then it pass all variables to the next page. if user not check any `check-box` it restrict user to check all checkboxes.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/1482555/4323504

Comment: This not doable with vanilla javascript. you will have to use a library like bPopup

Answer (score 4):

You can't have checkboxes/html in `alert()`, `confirm()` or `prompt()`. You might want to look into plugins like [bPopup](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/) and use those for this purpose.

Comment: This link is blockin my network. Can you please give me alternative

Answer (score 0):

You can create second form popup it on click (after you save the data from the first form) then act on second form to processed to next page...